# JavaFX: Way to check if event handler/filter has already been set?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

i'm having some issues with Event Handlers.
I want to check if an event handler has already been set to a node to prevent duplicate event handlers.

Consider this pseudocode:

```
if (!myNode.hasEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, this::doStuffOnPress):
     myNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, this::doStuffOnPress)
```

(If the node doesn't have this event handler already set, set it now)

Comment: This is not possible without accessing private members of some JavaFX classes. You need to save this kind of info somewhere else. Also comparing method references is iirc impossible or at least unreliable between jres.